# How do I get an initial view to load in android app?

Tags: android

I've been working on this app that was part of an assignment for a class I took last semester but I can't quite get it to work. According to the feedback my main issue is that "no initial views load to start the game" so the app just crashes.
This is my activity class:

```
public class GuessMasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView entityName;
    private TextView ticketsum;
    private Button guessButton;
    private EditText userIn;
    private Button btnclearContent;
    private String user_input;
    private ImageView entityImage;
    String answer;
    private int numOfEntities;
    private Entity[] entities;
    private int numOfTickets;
    private int[] tickets;
    String entName;
    int entityid =0;
    int currentTicketWon = 0;
    Politician trudeau = new Politician("Justin Trudeau", new Date("December", 25, 1971), "Male", "Liberal", 0.25);
    Singer dion = new Singer("Celine Dion", new Date("March", 30, 1968), "Female", "La voix du bon Dieu", new Date("November", 6, 1981), 0.5);
    Person myCreator = new Person("myCreator", new Date("September", 1, 2000), "Female", 1);
    Country usa = new Country("United States", new Date("July", 4, 1776), "Washington D.C.", 0.1);

    public GuessMasterActivity() {
        numOfEntities = 0;          //Initialize counter variables to zero
        numOfTickets = 0;
        entities = new Entity[100]; //Max number of entities possible in the game is 100

    }


    public void addEntity(Entity entity) {          //Adds selected entity to the game
        entities[numOfEntities++] = entity.clone(); //Invokes clone function to create a copy of selected entity and stores copy in entities array
    }



    public void playGame() {                                //Runs the game with selected entity

            userIn.getText().clear();
            int entityId = genRandomEntityId();

            Entity entity = entities[entityId];
            entityName.setText(entity.getName());
            String answer = userIn.getText().toString();                            //Reads user input
            answer = answer.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");

            if (answer.equals("quit")) {                                //Ends game if user inputs quit
                System.exit(0);
            }

            Date date = new Date(answer);

            if (date.precedes(entity.getBorn())) {                      //Evaluates user input
                AlertDialog.Builder Incorrect = new AlertDialog.Builder(GuessMasterActivity.this);
                Incorrect.setTitle("Incorrect");
                Incorrect.setMessage("Try a later date");

                Incorrect.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = Incorrect.create();
                dialog.show();
            } else if (entity.getBorn().precedes(date)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder Incorrect2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(GuessMasterActivity.this);
                Incorrect2.setTitle("Incorrect");
                Incorrect2.setMessage("Try an earlier date");

                Incorrect2.setNegativeButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Loading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = Incorrect2.create();
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                currentTicketWon = entity.getAwardedTicketNumber();
                this.numOfTickets = this.numOfTickets + entity.getAwardedTicketNumber(); //Updates total number of tickets for this game based on difficulty of selected entity
                AlertDialog.Builder win = new AlertDialog.Builder(GuessMasterActivity.this);
                win.setTitle("You Won");
                win.setMessage("Bingo"+entity.closingMessage());

                win.setNegativeButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"You won"+currentTicketWon+"tickets",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = win.create();
                dialog.show();
                ticketsum.setText(numOfTickets);
                ContinueGame();
            }

    }
    public void ImageSetter(){
        ImageView imgView = findViewById(R.id.entityImage);
        switch(entName){
            case("Justin Trudeau"):
                imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.justint);
                break;
            case("Celine Dion"):
                imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.celidion);
                break;
            case("United States"):
                imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.usaflag);
                break;
            case("myCreator"):
                imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic);
                break;
        }
    }
    public void ContinueGame(){
        entityid = genRandomEntityId();
        Entity entity = entities[entityid];
        entName = entity.getName();
        ImageSetter();
        entityName.setText(entName);
    }

    public int genRandomEntityId() {                                    //Selects random integer in the range of 0-the number of entities in the game
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        return randomNumber.nextInt(numOfEntities);
    }
    public void changeEntity(){
        userIn.setText("");
        playGame();
    }

    void welcomeToGame(Entity entity){
        AlertDialog.Builder welcomealert = new AlertDialog.Builder(GuessMasterActivity.this);
        welcomealert.setTitle("GuessMaster Game v3");
        welcomealert.setMessage(entity.welcomeMessage());
        welcomealert.setCancelable(false);

        welcomealert.setNegativeButton("START_GAME", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Game is Starting. . . Enjoy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = welcomealert.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addEntity(usa);
        addEntity(dion);
        addEntity(trudeau);
        addEntity(myCreator);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_guess_master);
        guessButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuess);
        userIn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.guessInput);
        ticketsum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ticket);
        entityImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.entityImage);
        entityName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.entityName);
        btnclearContent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnclearContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                changeEntity();
            }
        });
        guessButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playGame();
            }
        });
        final GuessMasterActivity gm = new GuessMasterActivity();
    }
}
```

And the XML layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.david.guessmaster.GuessMasterActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/ticket"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/entityImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/entityName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id = "@+id/guessInput"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnGuess"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I missing/where am I going wrong? I feel like I must be misunderstanding the flow of the app.

Comment: If the app crashes, post the crash log.  Your description of what's happening tells us nothing.  It doesn't crash because "no initial views load", it doesn't show any views because it crashes.  Although I can see several weirdnesses in your code (activities rarely->never have constructors, and should never be created via the new keyword).

Comment: It doesn't seem to be crashing anymore for some reason but it doesn't load the any picture at the start.

Instead of the constructor should everything be in the onCreate? and then I don't need the final GuessMasterActivity gm = new GuessMasterActivity line for anything right?